# How to let login and password available on VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using a pass through query on a VBA code to access an Oracle Database. The code works fine. My problem is: everytime I press the button on my form to run the code it asks me login and password to access the database and run the code. is there any way to let the login and password available on the code, so that I don't need to enter it every time I run the code?

Comment: Maybe you can check the connection string in your VBA code

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions I can think of

One approach is to re-create the connection for the pass-though query, and when you use the ODBC manager from Access, create a new connection (a file dsn), and check the box to remember your password when you save this connection.

Now in code you can go:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
   .SQL = "EXECute MyStoredProcedure "
   .ReturnsRecords = False
   .Execute
End With
```

And you can re-use the above PT over and over in your code. Change above retunsRecords if the stored procedure returns records, and use this:

So fill a record set, you can go:

```
Dim rst    as DAO.Recordset
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
   .SQL = "select * from dbo.tblCustomers"
   .ReturnsRecords = True
   Set rst = .OpenRecordSet
End With
```

The second idea is to logon on FIRST and then all PT or linked tables will work without a user + password.

You can also force a logon and keep your existing PT, and simply execute a logon like this:

```
Function TestLogin(strCon As String) As Boolean

   On Error GoTo TestError

   Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
   Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

   Set dbs = CurrentDb()
   Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.Connect = strCon

   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   qdf.SQL = "SELECT 1 from dual"
   qdf.Execute
   TestLogin = True

Exit Function

TestError:
    TestLogin = False
    Exit Function
End Function
```

So now, in your code, you can go:

```
Dim strCon    as string

strCon = "correct connection string with UID/PID"

IF TestLogon(strCon) = true then

   ‘ above pt example code

End If
```

So if your existing tables (and PT query) was NOT linked with the user + password, then executing the above logon will eliminate the logon prompt. In fact you only have to execute the above logon code ONE time on application start up, and after that you not receive a logon prompt when you run the PT query. Or open any linked table.

Once you execute the above logon code, then the user + password will remain in effect for all linked tables and PT query – they will not prompt for password. In fact this means that you can link all your tables and PT queries and NOT have to include the UID/Password which is in plane text and view by users. (so execute a logon, and then link all your tables without the user/password).

Comment: I don't get how to use the code above Albert. Is there a way of simply let the login and password available on code?

Comment: Yes - if you execute the above TestLogon code, then your existing query that is causing a "prompt" for logon will NOT appear. If you don't want to execute the above testlogon code on application startup, then you have to re-link the pass-though query and INCLUDE the userID/password when you re-link. using above code will prevent you having to re-link existing tables or pt quieries.  So the above code is HOW you in code supply the logon. Once above is done then any linked table or PT query will work without a logon prompt. So that simple logon code is how you make the logon/password in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try connection strings with ID and password :

```
Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
Integrated Security=no;
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/